# Export Unicode characters from SQL to CSV via PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, unicode, encoding

How do I export Unicode-y characters to CSV in PowerShell? Seems like `-Encoding UTF8` should do the trick.  I have the following object in PowerShell:

```
$data = @{"column" = "1/13/14->1/26/14"}
```

What I've actually got is a single-character unicode right-arrow coming from a SQL query, not the dash-greater-than symbols I've typed in above, but I can't seem to copy-paste the right-arrow into the Stack Overflow editor.  I believe the arrow character is successfully getting from SQL to PowerShell because I can log it to the PowerShell console:

[image]

Anyway, I want to export that object to CSV:

```
$table = $data.getEnumerator() | foreach{
  New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{column = $_.Value})
}
$table | export-csv export.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Problem is, the right-arrow fails to encode properly. Looking at the CSV in Notepad++, I see the too-familiar black `SUB` box where the arrow should be.

[image]

I've tried all the Export-CSV encodings listed on Microsoft's [Export-CSV page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx), to no avail. What am I missing about CSV and encoding here?  This sort of low-level data handling should be right in PowerShell's wheelhouse.  Is it possible that I need to do some kind of additional encoding management in the SQL -> PowerShell step?  There I'm using very straightforward ADO.Net:

```
function Invoke-Sql {
param(
    [string] $dataSource = ".\SQLEXPRESS",
    [string] $database = "MasterData",
    [string] $sqlCommand = $(throw "Please specify a query.")
  )

  $connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource; " +
        "Integrated Security=true; " +
        "Initial Catalog=$database"

  $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($connectionString)
  $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLCommand($sqlCommand,$connection)
  $connection.Open()

  $adapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $command
  $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
  $adapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null

  $connection.Close()
  return $dataSet   
}
```

Comment: Can you zip and upload the file somewhere so that we can look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I can't post pictures in a comment. I am unable to replicate the issue with Win8.1/PowerShell 4.0. I created an object with one property that contained a string for it's value which has the right arrow character in it. Code example:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> [pscustomobject]@{name="hello$([char]8594)there"}

name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
hello→there                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          


PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> [pscustomobject]@{name="hello$([char]8594)there"}|Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\temp\test.csv -Encoding UTF8
```

When I look at the file in Notepad++ it is output exactly as expected:

[image: Notepad++ Screenshot]
So I have to wonder what character SQL is outputting because it does not appear to be the unicode right facing arrow, character 8594.

My only real advise to you at this time is to close and re-open PowerShell to make sure everything is fresh, and then output to a new file that you haven't used before to make sure there's no encoding issues with an existing specific file.

Comment: It turns out SQL is giving me `nchar(26)` ("substitute"), not character 8594 ("right arrow").  Try the following in SQL to reproduce: select nchar(26) as unicodeForSubstitute, nchar(8594) as unicodeForRightArrow